# double - triple for loops using index of vectors that vary in length

Tags: kdb

I spent too much time on this searching for documentation or adequate example to no avail.
Kindly someone enlighten me how to deal with this problem.

Say I have the following table of orders for buying a stock. They will end at the designated time.

```
orders:([] seq:10*1+til 5; ID:5#`softbank;start:11:00 10:00 09:00 13:30 18:00;end:13:30 12:30 11:30 14:30 19:00)
```

For some reason I am hoping to find the maximum number of orders alive (say none are transacted) at a sub-time interval within the given time range between start and end. This is a very typical problem to test OOP implementation skills... to sort and deduct / add under if-else condition of time match with start time in the sequence in O(nlogn).

```
id 10: 3 (11-11:30 3, 11:30 -12 2(id 10/30), 12-12:30 2(id 10/20), 12:30 - 13:30 1) 
id 20: 2 (10-11 2 (id 20/30), 11-11:30 3 (id 10,20,30), 11:30-12:30 2 (id 10/20)
id 30: 2 (9-10 1, 10-11:30 2)
id 40: 1
id 50: 1
```

I can only think to iterate over two loops of `start`/`end`, with if condition inside. I also read including the piece that states loops are possible either with atomic variables or vectors of the same length. It cannot be possible the language is this limited though. Can anyone educate me or share with me link that is easy to follow...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I'm understanding the question correctly, you're trying to find how many orders are active (aka overlap) within each time window? If so then you can achieve it like this:

```
orders:([] seq:10*1+til 5; ID:5#`softbank;start:11:00 10:00 09:00 13:30 18:00;end:13:30 12:30 11:30 14:30 19:00);

/to get the count
q)update active:sum each (start<\:end)&end>\:start from orders
seq ID       start end   active
-------------------------------
10  softbank 11:00 13:30 3
20  softbank 10:00 12:30 3
30  softbank 09:00 11:30 3
40  softbank 13:30 14:30 1
50  softbank 18:00 19:00 1

/to get the seq numbers
q)update active:seq where each (start<\:end)&end>\:start from orders
seq ID       start end   active
---------------------------------
10  softbank 11:00 13:30 10 20 30
20  softbank 10:00 12:30 10 20 30
30  softbank 09:00 11:30 10 20 30
40  softbank 13:30 14:30 ,40
50  softbank 18:00 19:00 ,50
```

The reason you haven't found much documentation or examples on loops/indices/iteration is because kdb isn't designed for that approach. To make good use of kdb you have to avoid these concepts

EDIT - additional approach based on comments.

```
/intervals
iv:distinct asc raze orders`start`end;

/overlaps
update o:{1_{y,x}prior iv where(iv>=x)&iv<=y}'[start;end] from `orders;

/intersections
q)update o:o#\:{u[`seq]group(u:ungroup[x])`o}orders from orders
seq ID       start end   o
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
10  softbank 11:00 13:30 (11:00 11:30;11:30 12:30;12:30 13:30)!(10 20 30;10 20;,10)
20  softbank 10:00 12:30 (10:00 11:00;11:00 11:30;11:30 12:30)!(20 30;10 20 30;10 20)
30  softbank 09:00 11:30 (09:00 10:00;10:00 11:00;11:00 11:30)!(,30;20 30;10 20 30)
40  softbank 13:30 14:30 ,13:30 14:30!,,40
50  softbank 18:00 19:00 ,18:00 19:00!,,50

/if you want to know the counts
q)@[;`o;count'']update o:o#\:{u[`seq]group(u:ungroup[x])`o}orders from orders
seq ID       start end   o
--------------------------------------------------------------------
10  softbank 11:00 13:30 (11:00 11:30;11:30 12:30;12:30 13:30)!3 2 1
20  softbank 10:00 12:30 (10:00 11:00;11:00 11:30;11:30 12:30)!2 3 2
30  softbank 09:00 11:30 (09:00 10:00;10:00 11:00;11:00 11:30)!1 2 3
40  softbank 13:30 14:30 ,13:30 14:30!,1
50  softbank 18:00 19:00 ,18:00 19:00!,1

/if you want to see where the maximum overlap occurred
q)@[;`o;{#[;x]where c=max c:count each x}']update o:o#\:{u[`seq]group(u:ungroup[x])`o}orders from orders
seq ID       start end   o
-----------------------------------------------
10  softbank 11:00 13:30 ,11:00 11:30!,10 20 30
20  softbank 10:00 12:30 ,11:00 11:30!,10 20 30
30  softbank 09:00 11:30 ,11:00 11:30!,10 20 30
40  softbank 13:30 14:30 ,13:30 14:30!,,40
50  softbank 18:00 19:00 ,18:00 19:00!,,50
```

Comment: I think the question is asking per given time interval .. between 11:00 - 15:00 there are 11 to 12, 12 to 1, 1 to 2, 2 to 3. This is similar to counting the time range where there was maximum guests given the sequence of arrival/departure time. how were you to loop through these time frames?

Comment: Thanks for the update and the comment. This is right.. How do I return the maximum intersecting orders within the sub-intervals of each given timeframe?

Comment: this is why I was thinking in loop. I only see an iteration from the selected row + 01:00 until end.

Comment: Ok. You didn't mention 1-hour sub-intervals in your question. Please edit your original question to say that and please display what your expected final result is

Comment: Thank you. Yes and it actually isn't 1-hr sub-interval.. now that I think the interval may be variable.

Comment: I still don't understand your logic? What does this line mean `id 10: 3 (11-11:30 3, 11:30 -12 2(id 10/30), 12-12:30 2(id 10/20), 12:30 - 13:30 1)` ?

Comment: Sorry for the confusion. I only gave you the end result that should go under the column you created with 'active'. So for id 10, which is active 11 - 13:30, (i modified the data slightly) there will be an overlap with id 20 and 30 during 11 - 11:30, and the logic applies for the rest.

Comment: Ah yes, I didn't see that you had changed the input table. Will take a look now

Comment: But shouldn't 11:00-11:30 for seq=20 be equal to 3? There would be three active orders - seq 10, seq 20 and seq 30

Comment: Yes, so I mentioned 3.. as the maximum count. only on the ID 10, I will revise it to 3 for ID 20. Thank you. Do you see how to design this? Can you give me some ideas at least so that I may try and construct this?

Comment: It's hard to design if you keep changing it! I'll edit my answer to add another idea that might help you

Comment: this gives me less clue than your previous answer. Can I not find it for the given sequence? initially i had separately put together the sequence and looped through it...i think i can do this by iterating through each time in the `start` column.

Comment: Edited the answer again to show another approach. Not much more I can do beyond this

Comment: this is amazing, and I cannot thank you enough..Except that its complicated i cannot dare to modify into a version (without explanation step-by-step or some more hints) that would only retrieve the maximum of the sequence of numbers obtained in the last step per each row :[

Comment: Could you comment what is the `x` and `y` in each step if it doesn't trouble you too much..

Comment: and how can there be syntax like `count''`

Comment: It's too much to explain sorry, if you step through it piece by piece an use code.kx as a lookup tool then you should be able to get a grasp for it. My very first answer already gives you the maximum intersection!!!! If you need to know when the max occurred see my edit above

Comment: hm. i thought that's what i've been doing, but i just cannot find count``. and just as it is too much for you, its exponentially more for a novice to guess haha. R->L, if i try running in bits, like `(u:ungroup[x])` Q won't really understand.